# JavaScript color picker

Tags: javascript, draggable, color-picker

I found flexi color picker script that can give you color picked based on pure JavaScript, however it does not allow dragging to do selection, only clicking on palette.

I did little fix from:

```
if (slideElement.attachEvent) {
    slideElement.attachEvent('onclick', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement));
    pickerElement.attachEvent('onclick', pickerListener(this, pickerElement));
} else if (slideElement.addEventListener) {
    slideElement.addEventListener('click', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement), false);
    pickerElement.addEventListener('click', pickerListener(this, pickerElement), false);
}
```

to

```
if (slideElement.attachEvent) {
    slideElement.attachEvent('onmouseup', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement));
    slideElement.attachEvent('onmousedown', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement));

    pickerElement.attachEvent('onmouseup', pickerListener(this, pickerElement));
    pickerElement.attachEvent('onmousedown', pickerListener(this, pickerElement));
} else if (slideElement.addEventListener) {
    slideElement.addEventListener('mouseup', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement), false);
    slideElement.addEventListener('mousedown', slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement), false);

    pickerElement.addEventListener('mouseup', pickerListener(this, pickerElement), false);
    pickerElement.addEventListener('mousedown', pickerListener(this, pickerElement), false);
}
```

It works, however only works when page loads if you do it more than one time it starts to drag background image, is there way to fix that?

Also optional thing is to make it change color while holding mouse button and dragging mouse if possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/NkH3q/

Comment: I can't believe you are duplicating code to attach events all over the place, and then you go and add to the duplication with your "fix"

Comment: Do it better..., i did not say i was guru of javascript.

Comment: You don't have to be a guru in any language to recognize code duplication and improve it, it's not even part of the question, I'm just pointing out that you should have done that

Comment: And i still dont know what you talking about create answer with code example if you want to "point out" something or dont spam in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/NkH3q/3/

(does not work on IE8 < because I do not have IE to test it but you should be able to duplicate the handlers for IE and it should work without a problem).

Explanation.

What you are after, is to make the pickers move/drag only when the mouse is down. To achieve this you need to add a listener on *mousedown*

```
Elem.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
```

You notice that we do not have added a listener for *mouseup* event yet, and we won't at this point.
The startDragging function just sets a flag

```
this.dragging = false;
var q = this; // cache this to use it in another function scope

var startDragging = function() {
  q.dragging = true;  
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging , false);
};
```

All should be very clear. You 'll notice that we set the *mouseup* listener at the *document*. This is done to ensure that even if the user navigates his cursor out of the colorpicker, when the click is released (mouseup) the event will be caught by us.

Let's see how the *stopDragging* function should look like

```
    var stopDragging = function() {
      q.dragging = false;  
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging , false);
    };
```

Again, we set the dragging flag to false, and we remove the *mouseup* listener we set at the *document*. We don't want to litter the memm with listeners afterall.

And now the *mousemove* function

```
var pickerFunc = pickerListener(this, pickerElement ),
    slideFunc = slideListener(this, slideElement, pickerElement);

slideElement.addEventListener('mousemove', slideFunc, false);
pickerElement.addEventListener('mousemove',pickerFunc, false);

....
function pickerListener(ctx, pickerElement) {
    return function(evt) {
        if (!ctx.dragging)   
          return false;
.....
```

First of all since pickerListener/slideListener return functions there is no need to call them more than once, provided we use the same arguments every time. Because we will end up with duplicate functions. Therefore it is much better to do that once and cache them (slideFunc/pickerFunc vars)

Then in the beginning of those functions we add a check for the dragging flag. If it set to false, we do nothing.

In order to prevent things from being selected and ruining the 'drag' control, we need to add

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none; 
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

at the wrapper element. Older versions of IE (7,8,9) and Opera require a *unselectable="on"*  attribute at the wrapper element.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is kind of buggy 
1. page loaded you click and drag then release - it worked
2. you try same again and it drags background, you released mouse and color picker still following cursor.

So you fixed optional thing, but main problem still there it drags background every time after first time you try.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NkH3q/3/  Fixed. Added css rule to prevent user-selection from happening (see the css rule for .wrapper)

Comment: You are the man, i was looking for solution to that dragging background problem in JavaScript code, but it was just CSS thing, Cool.

Comment: Yes user-select is css3. It is not supported in IE8, not even IE9 (also not in opera yet). Perhaps IE didnot had the drag problem to start with. If you want the alternative for IE (and opera too), then please add unselectable="on" at your wrapper element :)